# Equivalent RDD ForEach of Spark in Flink

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, apache-flink, flink-streaming

in Apache Spark,many times we use RDD forEach to evaluate or process each data in RDD...I want to know what is the equivalent for the same in Apache Flink ??

Answer (score 0):

There is no equivalent in Flink. However, you can use a `map()` and put your custom function in there.

Just to clarify:

1. RDDs are a Spark concept -- Flink does work on data streams.
2. `forEach` calls a function for each element, but does not modify the underlying data (thus, using `map()` in Flink, you need to put an "identity function with side effect" -- ie, your map UDF should do whatever forEach UDF does, plus emit the input record unmodified.)

Answer (score 0):

Since version 1.2 Flink offers `ProcessFunction` which is more or less analogous to `forEach` in Spark, in that it is called for each stream element.